# Outlook - Converting Plain Text to HTML - Doesn't work in 2007

Tags: c#, com, outlook, outlook-addin, outlook-2007

See my original question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6124865/c-sharp-vsto-add-in-convert-plain-text-email-to-html).

This works great if you are using Outlook 2010, but doesn't seem to work in Outlook 2007.

In 2007, it gets converted to HTML, but the font is not correct.  It works properly if I click the HTML button manually in the Ribbon UI.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have long ago moved on from this issue.

I'm assuming there is no fix.